# Android Management API not working in Korea

Tags: android-management-api

We have a customer in Korea who has an issue enrolling its devices with the Android Management API.

[The download link of the Device Policy APK](https://play.google.com/managed/downloadManagingApp?identifier=setup) returns an HTTP 500 error. The customer tried loading this link on his browser through a WiFi network and got the same error. He also tried loading it on his smartphone from a 3G network and also got the same error.

[Screenshot available here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qj5gbdjcmpcicxz/http500.jpg?dl=0)

On my side (from France), I can download the APK without any problem.

Are you aware of any network issue accessing the Play Store from Seoul, Korea?

BTW, the Korean message on the screenshot states: *There was an error. Please try again later. That's all we know.* :)

Florian

Comment: Could it be due to the firewall or proxy of the customer?

Comment: Hi Fred, I'll double check with the customer and let you know, thanks!

Comment: It's actually due to the Android Management API not being available in Korea. See my reply below.

Comment: The Android Management API is now available in Korea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update (2019-04-16):** The Android Management API is now available in Korea.

---

As of today (2019-02-12) the Android Management API is not available in Korea. We are working on making it available.

As a consequence it's currently not possible to set up devices in Korea (IP based),  however devices set up outside of Korea can then be used in Korea without issues.

Comment: Hi Fred, thanks a lot for your reply. As a workaround, we've downloaded your DPC, then have hosted it on a server managed by the customer. After generating a new enrolment QR Code, we were able to enrol devices.

Comment: Hi Florian, this seems to be a good workaround, just remember to update the DPC when a new version is released (see [release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/management/release-notes)).

Comment: Thanks Fred for the advice. How should we proceed in that case?

Comment: You just need to regularly update the hosted APK, so that it's not too old, until we fix the root issue.

Comment: The Android Management API is now available in Korea.

Answer (score 0):

use vpn to download app. google store is based on ip so you can be hard to find it